# How to calculate values without rounding them?

Tags: c++, rounding

If i calculate `0,703125 / 2` with calc.exe, then i get `0,3515625`. However, if i do the same in C++ then i get `0,351563`. How can i turn rounding off? I need the full number.

Background

I try to find out if it is true that the pattern in the following example will always result to 9.

```
360° = 3+6+0 = 9
180° = 1+8+0 = 9
90° = 9+0 = 9
45° = 4+5 = 9
22.5° = 2+2+5 = 9
11.25° = 1+1+2+5 = 9
5.625° = 5+6+2+5 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
2.8125° = 2+8+1+2+5 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
1.40625 = 1+4+0+6+2+5 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
0.703125 = 0+7+0+3+1+2+5 = 18 = 1+8 = 9
0.3515625 = 0+3+5+1+5+6+2+5 = 27 = 2+7 = 9
0.17578125 = 0+1+7+5+7+8+1+2+5 = 36 = 3+6 = 9
...
```

I already wrote [the code](http://www.pasteall.org/61345/cpp) for this, but because C++ rounds the values, i get false results. How can i solve this?

Code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>       /* pow */
using namespace std;

int checksum(int param)
{
    int sum = 0;


    while (param > 0)
    {
        int r1 = param % 10;
        sum += r1;
        param /= 10;
    }

    while (sum > 9) { sum = checksum(sum); } 

    return sum;
}

//This function just takes a double and separates it in two parts. 
//The part in front of the point, and the part behind the point.
//Then it calls my checksum function with both of them and gives the result.

int tesla(double param)
{

    int     front_part              = static_cast<int>(param);
    double  after_point_part        = param - front_part;

    ostringstream strs;  
    strs << after_point_part;
    string after_point_part_str = strs.str();


    int nachkomma_len = after_point_part_str.length()-1;

    after_point_part *= pow(10.00,nachkomma_len-1);

    strs.str("");                                                                                           //so leert man einen stringstream
    strs << after_point_part;
    after_point_part_str = strs.str();

    int after_point_part_int = stoi(after_point_part_str);

    int SUM = 0;

    SUM = checksum(front_part);
    SUM += checksum(after_point_part_int);
    SUM = checksum(SUM);

    return SUM;
}



int main()
{
    double number; 
    cout<<"Enter number:"<<endl;
    cin>> number;

    int zähler = 100;

    for(int i=0; i < zähler; i++)
    {
        int erg = tesla(number);
        cout<<"The checksum of "<<number<<" is "<< erg <<endl;  
        number /= 2;
    }

    cin.get(); cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want rounding, you have to use floating point variables, not integers.

Comment: Please show your code. It sounds like the problem is you're using `float` when you should use `double`, to get more digits of precision. But eventually you'll run into a limit.

Comment: What's the full number when you divide 10 by 3? Related question: How much disk space and time do you have?

Comment: @Alex I think he meant all the precision values.

Comment: Please post any relevant code in your question, not as a link which will someday surely die.

Comment: It is also not clear in the code you've linked to where the problem occurs.   However, the two likely explanations (both of which are relevant to parts of your code) are doing integer division (which is required to round) or running into limited precision of floating point types - both for calculations and default output formats.  `calc` has unlimited precision - within memory constraints.

Comment: How are you planning on adding up all the digits of a number with a repeating decimal? E.g. `1/7` is `.142857142857142857...`

Comment: @Barmar, the code is linked. I use double

Comment: Don't just link the code, put it in the question.

Comment: @Barmar stackoverflow did not allowed me to put it in the question because it was too much code, but now i edited it in.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things going on here:

- The number you see printed is for your enjoyment (or perhaps, your frustration). If you want to see better precision than the default, specify that you want to see better precision than the default. How a number is printed and how it is represented are two very different things.
- You need to use double precision if you want more than six or so decimal places of precision. You need to use some kind of extended precision if you want more than fifteen or so decimal places of precision.
- Ultimately, there is no escape. Fully representing the rational numbers would require a computer with infinite memory. You can't represent the rationals in their full detail on a finite binary (or digital) computer.
- To fully represent the real numbers is beyond that. The number of real numbers is uncountable.

Comment: Even some rational numbers have an infinite number of digits after the decimal point, so the idea of adding up all the digits makes no sense. E.g. 1/3 is `0.333333333...`.

Comment: So OP needs infinite Monkeys with infinite computers and infinite RAM. I don't see the problem.

Comment: @user4581301if this is the only problem, then i am good to go.

Comment: Computer are not able to do anything is what i learned today.

Answer (score 2):

No need to calculate anything. Any number divisible by 9 will have the sum of its digits divisible by 9 (https://sites.google.com/site/mathematicsnotebook/divisibilityrules/divisibility9)

360 is divisible by 9, and division by 2 and counting digits is the equivalent of multiplication by 5: 360/2 = 360 * 0.5, multiply by 10 to get all digits to the left of the decimal point.

So no matter how many times you divide by 2, the resulting number stays divisible by 9. So is its sum of digits, and so is the sum's sum of digits.